# Paypal Instant Update API - MAXAMT Error

Tags: php, api, paypal

since hours I try to solve the following error from the [paypal Instant Update API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECInstantUpdateAPI)

```
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 11832
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Maximum amount of order is less than itemized amounts.
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Maximum amount of order is less than itemized amounts.
```

Here is the Request:

```
Method: SetExpressCheckout
Request: 
Formatted Request: Array
(
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 3.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 1.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 1.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL] => http://www.eee.de/ipn.php
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CALLBACK] => http://www.eee.de/ajax.php?action=eee
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_MAXAMT] => 11.00
    [LOGO] => https://www.eee.de/template/img/logo-eee.png
    [CANCELURL] => http://eee.de/bestellung.php?paypal_express=cancel
    [RETURNURL] => http://eee.de/bestellung.php?paypal_express=return
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 1.00
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Item
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Desc
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
    [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 123
    [CALLBACKVERSION] => 82.0
    [CALLBACK] => http://www.eee.de/ajax.php?action=ppe_shipping
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0] => true
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0] => UPS0
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0] => 1.00
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1] => false
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1] => UPS2
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1] => 2.00
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2] => false
    [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2] => 3.00
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED] => true
    [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT] => 1.00
)
```

I tried every combination of values

this is the response from the Callbackurl:

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse
&OFFERINSURANCEOPTION=true
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=UPS0
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=1.00
&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT0=1.00
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=UPS1
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=2.00
&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT1=1.00
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=UPS2
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=3.00
&L_INSURANCEAMOUNT2=1.00
&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false
```

As far as I understand, the MAXAMT value is the total of items + max shipping + tax + factor x so why to hell does it compare it this way? 11.00 < 3.00 (3.00 = item+shipping+insurance)

I am totally lost!
Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use MAXAMT instead of PAYMENTREQUEST_0_MAXAMT.

Actually the PayPal documentation sucks as same things are described totally differently in PayPal documentation.